# How do i determine how many results to display based on screen resolution?

Tags: javascript, css, html, sass

Im busy developing a phonegap app using html css js have php mysql to get data. Im doing a ajax call that returns json data that is formatted and appended into ul list and displayed on the screen. my problem now is each device has different screen size resolution. how do i determine how many results to display based on screen resolution? Displaying 5 records on a small phone looks okay but on a tablet it makes no sense to show 5 records with a big screen and then having to page.  I was thinking to have a case statement that checks screen resolution and then show number of records based on that... im asking is there a better way i can do this?

Comment: Why did i get a negative?

Comment: What ever works best for you and your users. You'll go nuts trying to hit the _sweet spot_ of every screen size. Even if we could see your design and the content your talking about, it's going to be subjective. You might feel 5 for a smartphone is good but 6,8 or 10 might be acceptable too. In the end I wouldn't get too hung up on these numbers right away and ballpark how many you show by rough device size know that inbetween isn't going to be 100% perfect, i.e. Smartphone - 5, Tablet - 10, Desktop - 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it!

On device StartUp/PageLoad, run a script that gets the height of the device.

HTML

```
<body onLoad="get_DeviceHeight()">
```

JavaScript

```
var DeviceHeight;
function get_DeviceHeight()
{
  DeviceHeight = window.innerheight;
}
```

Then divide **DeviceHeight** by the height of a single (**record height**).

```
var AmountToDisplay = DeviceHeight / RecordHeight.
```

Then input the AmountToDisplay  into your loop for outputting records onto the screen.

```
for (i = 0; i <= AmountToDisplay; i++) { 
    printRecord[i] to the display;
}
```

Comment: @Alfred Alfizo Mosima: When i saw your question there were already two negative votes. I made sure to give you my **upvote** because i know how lame the community here could be. Some people will down vote others if they are unable to answer the question.

Comment: "_Some people will down vote others if they are unable to answer the question._" I doubt that statement is true, I think thats just your assumption. People normally down vote, I think, because usually a question is either opinion based or shows no code effort.

Comment: @Really Nice Code Thanks man, let me give your solution a try it seems very interesting.

Comment: @zgood I dont need to show code i don't have an error its a solution to a problem, the problem is really straight forward im sure someone out there has had the same issues.

Comment: @zgood _I doubt that statement is true, I think thats just your assumption_  ...nope its not an assumption, its my experience on this site. i make sure to properly construct my questions, giving a scenario, and sample code. I even state why other methods will not work. I even go as far as to include the code i am working on for others to see... And still, people who can not contribute to answering the question will down vote it. >>As long as a question is clear and easy to understand there is not always a need to include code.  This site is both 'a heaven sent' and 'totally mean' at times.